# Kubernetes: nodes joining a cluster - unable to connect to master

Tags: kubernetes

I've got 3 VMs which can connect.

I've started up 1 master and 2 nodes.

However, I'm not sure what IP address to use here:

```
sudo kubeadm join <ip address>:6443     --token <token>     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash <ca-cert-hash>
```

The actual IP I used to deploy the master (i.e. with `kubeadm`) was `192.168.56.101`. 
And I can telnet from the node to the master using:

`telnet 192.168.56.101 6443`

E.g.

```
telnet 192.168.56.101 6443
Trying 192.168.56.101...
Connected to 192.168.56.101.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

However trying `kubeadm join` on the node with that IP does not work. It just hangs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could You provide information about how You create your master cluster? After using `kubeadm init` there should be information `You can now join any number of machines by running the following on each node
as root:

  kubeadm join <control-plane-host>:<control-plane-port> --token <token> --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:<hash>`

Answer (score 0):

run 'hostname -i' and grab the IP address. Use it in init command. The master IP address should be reachable from all the nodes

Comment: then it is a problem. you need to update hostnames and ip addresses correctly in /etc/hosts file in master and the workers. then use master IP address. it should work

Answer (score 0):

run

## kubectl cluster-info

Kubernetes master is running at https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:6443

KubeDNS is running at https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

Kubernetes master IP it's what you are looking for

Did you deployed your CNI network ? Flannel or Calico for example ?

run this command to see if all your master pods are running.

kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

In your Node did you install docker and kubelet  ?